# Definition of basis and cobasis in a chart

Tags: financial-literacy, terminology, chart

In this article https://monetary-metals.com/silver-price-spikes-but-what-demand-4-oct-2015/, there is a chart of *basis* and *cobasis*.

For basis I found too many different meanings and for cobasis nothing that seems relevant to me.

How are they defined and measured? 
How are they usually interpreted?

Answer (score 3):

Basis and Cobasis try to measure the scarcity of something
by measuring how profitable it is to buy something now at spot price and sell it simultaneously as a future or vice versa.

Definition:

```
Basis = Future(bid) – Spot(ask)
Cobasis = Spot(bid) – Future(ask)
```

Full article:
https://monetary-metals.com/basiscobasis/